# How to use flash object in Sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have a Sidekiq worker like this:

```
class MyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    message = SomeImportantClass.new.get_message
    flash.now[:notice] = message 
  end
 end
```

So when the user visits page the worker is launched. Without leaving the page user gets notification from Sidekiq worker.
I'm not so experienced in this field so I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access `flash` from workers, because they are outside of request context.

You'll have to communicate with your request context via some kind of storage (your main DB or memcached/redis, for example).

The outline is like this:

1. Store your message in the storage

   ```
   class MyWorker
     include Sidekiq::Worker

     def perform
       message = SomeImportantClass.new.get_message
       redis.set("messages:#{message.user.id.to_s}") = message.text
     end
    end
   ```
2. Make an endpoint in your app that will show these messages for the current user

   ```
    class MyController
      def status
        msg = redis.get("messages:#{current_user.id.to_s}")
        render text: msg
      end
    end
   ```
3. Have client-side JS poll this endpoint and show a notification/modal/whatever when it gets a message.

You have to use the polling or other mechanism of async update (websockets, etc.), because without it, once page is rendered, it won't automagically know about progress of your worker.