# How to display flash object after sidekiq worker finishes-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, flash-message

I am trying to display reminder notification as a flash message in my rails app using sidekiq. I learnt how to set the flash message in the worker from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35748553/5990280).

As mentioned in the last point of that answer, how to show the notification automatically, when an entry is made?

Also how to delete that entry once the flash message is closed?

I'm a beginner. Kindly help.

As requested, I'm adding my code attempt:

In my controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  msg = $redis.get("messages:#{@user.id}")
  flash[:info] = msg if !msg.nil?
end
```

In my sidekiq worker:

```
def perform user, type
  @user = user`enter code here`
  message = "Message content"
  $redis.set("messages:#{user.id}", message)
end
```

What I want is to refresh user page when the redis key is set and also delete the  pair when the close button of the flash is pressed.

Comment: _"how to show the notification automatically..."_ **show your code** attempt for this task, that we can help you to fix.

Comment: I have added code as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Sidekiq is designed for **asynchronous** job processing.  Once you've created a job, your controller is done and renders the page for the browser.  Your job might be processed 1ms from now or 1 hour from now, you don't know.  In other words, you can't do what you want.  You should design your page flow to either account for this or don't create a background job for the work.

Comment: Well, I realized that soon and hence made an entry to redis. My controller will display the message in redis if the entry is present. The problem, now, is how to automatically refresh the page when an entry to redis is made.